# Sort data by numeric and alphabetical in sqlite3

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have table data like this:

```html
ID  name
----------
1    30
2    aaa
3    zzz
4    20
5    40
6    10

My result should be sorted data 

ID  name
5    40
1    30
4    20
6    10
3    zzz
2    aaa
```

Means numeric and alphabetic should be separate and it should be sorted in DESC or ASC.

If anyone have an idea to perform this operation in sqlite3 help me

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM yourTableName ORDER BY ID ASC;
```

If you want something more detailed than that, it would help to know what you are currently running or what you want the output to be.